# Is it possible to redirect messages from a business Facebook page to my personal profile or email?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Specifically, the messages would not even appear in the page's inbox. I'm sure this is not possible but I'm just checking for some paranoid people!

Answer (score 0):

**No**, officially it's not possible. I am not sure about any third party tool or script.

You cannot redirect messages from a business page to your personal profile or email. You can turn on email notification for messages to receive messages on registered email also. But it will still appear in the page's inbox.